# Beginning Java Web services. Where to start

Tags: java, service, tomcat, jboss

my company runs a site that primarily has its backend logic coded in Perl. It works fine but ultimately we are headed to something Java driven. I do plan on studying this and would like to start setting up a Java environment on another server in our company so when the time comes I at least have a headstart.
Does anyone have a recommendation on where to begin? Just interested in generalities now.
JW

Answer (score 1):

What are you planning to study? All Java or just the web service extensions?

If you come from Perl, I must suggest you starting from "hello world" with a [Java cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007010), then you can start moving towards web services after a while.
Another [good book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520731?green=15843935502&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596520731.IP) about web service is what you might need.

Finally, when beginning to build the web service, I suggest you two things:

1. Design the WSDL independently from Java code that will implement it. It's very important for cross-platform interoperability. Try to use Altova XMLSpy or a similar tool to define the pure WSDL as a design contract
2. Deploy with [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/index.html)

I don't know how to propose to move this question to Stackoverflow, because you can find LOTS of answers there

Comment: @djechelon: Just the web service stuff. I actually have a rudimentary understanding of Java already. I would have asked this question on S.O. but it's been my experience that this kind of question only results in "why didn't you ask this on S.U.?"

Comment: Hahaha, ok then you can start from the second book. Once you finish with it, you'll be mastering web services more than I do (because I'm a .NET miscredant)... EDIT: here we are on SO anyway :)

Comment: I would STRONGLY recommend that you don't use Axis unless you have no other options (e.g. you're forced to by work).  First of all, Axis is very outdated -- at the very least you should use Axis2.  However, Axis2 is such a poorly documented pile of garbage that I would suggest you look elsewhere: Metro, XFire, etc.  See http://www.bileblog.org/2006/05/axis2-why-bother/ for a somewhat dated, but still relevant explanation of why you want to avoid any version of Axis.

Comment: @Segphault I personally like working with Axis. So it can't be all that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need J2EE
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/

Java Tutorial
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

General Java Stuff
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/overview/gettingstarted-jsp-138588.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/webapps-1-138794.html

About the Class Path
http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Comment: WOW! Now THAT is a good answer. Hopefully I can start with more of a "Hello World" and go from there.

Comment: There is a "Hello World" example. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html